# Is there a complete connectome of a minicolumn of the neocortex?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, neuroanatomy

I know that there are [projects](http://www.humanconnectomeproject.org) that try to map brain connectivity. My question is whether there is a dataset available with the complete connectivity of just a single [minicolumn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_minicolumn) of the neocortex. Doesn't have to be human.

Comment: check out blue brain project of markram.  they are the main attempt of trying to do that

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. The closest publication would be [Lee et al 2016](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature17192), which is a reconstruction of a network of functionally-characterised neurons in mouse V1. They state the data "will be available" at [neurodata](http://neurodata.io/lee16); currently only the EM dataset appears to be there, and not the correspondence with functional imaging. I encourage you to contact them for the data set.

Alternatively, there are functional measurements and small networks available from mouse visual cortex [Cossell et al. 2015](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/072595) (self-cite; data available on request); and anatomical statistical measurements available from rat somatosensory cortex [Markram et al. 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2015.09.029) (data available from [NMC](https://bbp.epfl.ch/nmc-portal)).